# None of my MATLAB variables from my function are appearing in my workspace? I don't want them to be output variables

Tags: matlab, variables, workspace

[image]

Why aren't any of the varibles from `filter_img` appearing in my workspace? This would be very helpful to my debugging.

I also need to clarify the fact that these variables used to appear on my workspace without them being outputs.

Comment: You shouldn't use that many loops... Example: to get `max_value` you can do `max_value = max(spec_img(:));` etc.

Comment: I don't understand why this would be downvoted without someone giving me a reason.

Comment: How does downvoting a question without a comment actually going to help people ask better questions?

Comment: @Dev-iL That's a good point. I'll tidy my code up when the program runs.

Comment: The downvotes are because this is a very basic MATLAB feature, and shows little knowledge. However I believe its a fair question.

Comment: Read this: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're in a function so they're only in your workspace while the function is executing. Once it is done, they will no longer be in your workspace.

To see them, you can type `keyboard` somewhere in the function and then use the matlab debugger to step through your function, checking the values of the variables in the command window.

Comment: though, the most concise, this is the most helpful and correct answer! I'll accept this in 5 minutes

Comment: For a more general answer I would recommend also including [setting breakpoints for the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html). `keyboard` is useful but MATLAB's various breakpoint methodologies are very powerful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see them on your workspace, use a script instead of a function or return all the necessary parameters as function outputs. [See base and function workspaces](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html). There are other ways for sharing variables between workspaces, like persistent variables, global variables or might look for the `evalin` command.

Comment: thank you for the link, but I was aware of all of this. It just seems a bit counterintuitive for the function variables not to appear in the workspace and I was wondering if there is a forced way to make them appear.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala It's very intuitive for a function not to clutter the workspace, that's what you mainly use them for. If you want to have them anyway, add them to the output, or, God forbid, use `global` variables

Comment: haha going to absolutely stay away from those `global` variables. But yes, it does make sense.

Comment: In some cases global variables make the program easier to understand, than using long function parameter lists. In those cases perhaps think of using OO style as objects can organize themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly:

In order for you to see variables of a function in Matlab you have to run the code with a breakpoint set after the variable you want to see.

If you just run it like this it will just run through (or crash) without the variables being saved in the workspace.

It looks to me with

->> filter_img

->>

sign that you have run it but without any breakpoints. They are red next to the line numbers in the editor window.

I hope this helps.

Comment: They are two ways of doing it: 1. click on the line where you want to add the breakpoint (preferably right after the variable is set you want to see in the workspace). then press F12 or click in the editor window on breakpoints and set/clear breakpoints. 2. you can click on the right side of the line number that works if the settings are correct.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm looking at [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) right now!

Answer (score 1):

In a matlab function all variables created in that function are local to it and unless they are an output are deleted when the function finishes.

To see the variables either make your function a script, by deleting the function line or add a breakpoint somewhere in your function (by clicking next to the line number before running.

Generally, for this reason having a function with no inputs or outputs in matlab is a bit pointless so you should probably change that anyway.